# Does the a-frame's text component really have a yOffset property?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to use a property of the aframe's text component called yOffset. This property is not listed in the documentation but appears in the component's schema. When applied nothing happens. The xOffset and zOffset properties normally work by shifting the text along their respective axes.

[image]

This is a basic example to demonstrate. In theory the text on the a-plane should be shifted 10cm downwards, but nothing happens.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D">
        <a-plane
          material="shader: flat"
          color="#444357"
          position="0 1.1 0"
          width="1.4"
          height="0.4"
          text="value: LABEL; width: 2; letterSpacing: 10px; yOffset: 1; align: center;"
        ></a-plane>
      </a-cylinder>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to exemple in glitch [example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gold-diligent-lyric)

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v1.4.0/src/components/text.js#L84):

> // `yOffset` to adjust generated fonts from tools that may have incorrect metrics.

Looks like it's a feature for other-than-default fonts in case the glyphs are off. Once you load a font its working:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-plane
     material="shader: flat"
     color="#444357"
     position="0 1.1 -1"
     width="1.4"
     height="0.4"
     text="font: https://cdn.aframe.io/fonts/mozillavr.fnt;
           value: LABEL; width: 2; letterSpacing: 10px; yOffset:50; align: center;">
  </a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

Not sure if it's intended for positioning, rather than fixes.

Comment: Yes it works with stock fonts except Roboto(default). Which makes me wonder if the problem is just with msdf fonts, because in my tests I'm using a custom Montserrat font created with the web-based MSDF tool https://msdf-bmfont.donmccurdy.com/